# Achieving Core Data Consistency in Android

Tags: android, ios, core-data, orm

I would like to know how I can achieve the consistency feature of Core Data on iOS on Android. As far as I know, Core data will always keep the NSManagedObject instance in sync(for the particular context) during the application lifetime.

How would I achieve this feature on the Android platform?

Are there any good ORM libraries on Android which ensure that the objects are always consistent over all the screens in the Android application?

Thanks
Amandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve the same constancy with a ORM library, where models keeps as objects , and You can try ,

GreenDAO  [here](http://greendao-orm.com/)

ORMLite [here](http://ormlite.com/)

SUGER ORM [here](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/)

and there are many more